# making phone call in android

Tags: android

Making a Call through android device via phone and the code does not seems to work

I am call this function

```
private void call() {
    try {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("912345678"));
        startActivity(callIntent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {
        Log.e("dialing-example", "Call failed", activityException);
    }
}
```

also I have given the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

What am I doing wrong any one can guide me?

Comment: What means "does not seem to work"?

Comment: This will just open the dialler with the number filled in right? Don't think we can make an outgoing call without user intervention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
                       startActivity(intent);
```

make permission in manifest file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:91234566"));
```

If you do not specify the scheme of the URI (`tel:` in this case), it won't be recognized as a phone number and hence, the desired action will not occur.

Comment: Ok its working.. but when i end the call my current activity doesn't get killed what should i do?

Comment: Add `android:noHistory="true"` to your `AndroidManifest.xml`